# Print MySQL data into HTML page using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

This is my first time learning Node.js. I am trying to print the data in MySQL into my HTML page, but whenever I load my website on the browser `http://localhost:3000/index.html`, I get this message on the webpage: `Cannot GET /index.html`. However when I load this `http://localhost:3000/rows/` on the browser, I get the data from MySQL as the output `[{"ID":1,"Name":"Wendy Smith","Message":"Hello, how are you?"}]`.

I have posted the code below. I am struggling to resolve this issue.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My db rows</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>My Data</h1>

        <div id="output"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var opts = {
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/rows/'
             };

             fetch(opts)
                 .then((res) => {
                     if (res.ok) {
                         return res.json();
                     }
                  })
                  .catch(console.log);
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'))
var mysql = require('mysql'); 

var connection = mysql.createConnection({  
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mywebsite"
});        

app.get('/rows', function (req, res) {
    connection.connect();  
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows, fields) {  
        connection.end();
        if (err) throw err;  
        res.json(rows); 
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Connected to port 3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the middleware code to route the request through the index.html page. Say for example you have set a `const` variable in your `app.js` as such:

```
const indexRouter = require("./app_server/router/index.html");
```

You can render the `html` page as such:

```
app.use("/", indexRouter);
```

In case you want to use the `express.static` middleware to serve static files that are in a `public` folder, just use:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Comment: On the sever response, I get `Error: Cannot find module`

Comment: Can you test this out without defining the const variable as such: app.use("/", function(req, res) { res.send("This is a test");}

Comment: What do you mean ? Did you sort it out ?

Comment: `This is a test` is displayed on my webpage

Comment: Which then means you have a solution :) You just have to wire your `html` page to the code, wherever it resides in your local directory

Comment: Like this: `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));`

Comment: Did you sort this out? If you want to use the `express.static` middleware I will edit my answer.

Comment: It works but the data from MySQL doesn't show up on my HTML page.

Comment: I used this first: `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));`

Comment: Then I used this: `app.use('/', function(req, res) { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); });`